# WPF - VB Accessing control within a Listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I know there are many posts like this one but I have searched for days and none seem to get the right answer for me. I have a databound Listbox that contains results of a dataset. One of those results is a decimalised percentage of which I wish to use to populate a single bar chart per row. I decided the easiest way (surely) to do this would be to use the rectangle control and use the databound value to control its width property... Simple!

However, I am really struggling to be able to access the rectangle control from within the List box Item. Here is a sample of my WPF:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbResults" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="578" Margin="10,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="754">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Border BorderBrush="#FFDEDFFF" Margin="3" Padding="1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FFF8F8FD" >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2E3FF" Width="200" Margin="3" Padding="1" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FFF3F4FF" >

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                    <Label Content="{Binding FULLNAME}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="1"/>

                                    <Label Name="lblPot" Padding="1">
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <Binding Path="POT"/>
                                        </Label.Content>
                                        <Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                            Pot: {0}
                                        </Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label Padding="1">
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <Binding Path="POTSTATUS"/>
                                        </Label.Content>
                                        <Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                            Status: {0}
                                        </Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label Padding="1">
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <Binding Path="DAYSTODAY"/>
                                        </Label.Content>
                                        <Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                            Days: {0}
                                        </Label.ContentStringFormat>
                                    </Label>


                                </StackPanel>

                            </Border>

                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2E3FF" Width="295" Margin="3" Padding="5" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FFF3F4FF" >

                                <StackPanel Name="spProgress" Orientation="Vertical">

                                    <Label Content="{Binding Complete}" Padding="1"/>


                                    <Border BorderBrush="#FFE2E3FF"  BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Height="30" Width="280">

                                        <Rectangle Name="rctProgSuccess" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
                                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF54EE62" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                                        </Rectangle>

                                    </Border>

                                </StackPanel>

                            </Border>


                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I have attempted various ways to access this rectangle control in code behind in order to manupulate its width value but have so far failed. My latest attempt looks like:

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To lbResults.Items.Count - 1

            Dim myListBoxItem As ListBoxItem = DirectCast(lbResults.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i), ListBoxItem)
            Dim myContentPresenter As ContentPresenter = FindVisualChild(Of ContentPresenter)(myListBoxItem)
            Dim myDataTemplate As DataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate

            Dim rctSuccess As Rectangle = DirectCast(myDataTemplate.FindName("rctProgSuccess", myContentPresenter), Rectangle)


            rctSuccess.Width = 100
            rctSuccess.Fill = Brushes.Red

        Next
```

With the following function:

Private Function FindVisualChild(Of childItem As DependencyObject)(obj As DependencyObject) As childItem

```
For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj) - 1

    Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i)

    If child IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf child Is childItem Then
        Return DirectCast(child, childItem)
    Else

        Dim childOfChild As childItem = FindVisualChild(Of childItem)(child)
        If childOfChild IsNot Nothing Then
            Return childOfChild
        End If

    End If

Next

Return Nothing
```

End Function

However the myListBoxItem declared always populates empty. I am sure I am missing something fundamental here but I am literally out on my ear and am happy to hear any feedback - even if there is a totally different way to achieve what I am doing... using DataGrids or anything??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem, something like this should work. First: handle the Loaded event on your Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Loaded="rctProgSuccess_Loaded" Name="rctProgSuccess" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280">
    ...
</Rectangle>
```

This will call the `rctProgSuccess_Loaded` method for each of your rectangles, passing the rectangle instance as a parameter. In your code-behind, simply do:

```
Private Sub rctProgSuccess_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim rctProgSuccess As Rectangle = DirectCast(sender, Rectangle)

    'Obviously edit the following part to match the type of data of the items that populate your ListBox
    Dim yourItem As YourClass = DirectCast(rctProgSuccess.DataContext, YourClass)
    rctProgSuccess.Width = yourItem.yourPercentage 'or whatever
End Sub
```

Comment: That is just fantastic!! First hurdle well overcome! Thanks very much for that. Just coming at it from a different (now obvious) angle has made the difference!

Comment: Actually - I got this working great - so again, thanks for that... I have set the Datacontext in the XAML for the rectangle as the value that drives the percentage (e.g. 0.75 for 75%) and multiplied this by the existing width... this gives me the exact result I need... however, I now need to do another chart (the same as this) but I need two values from the dataset for this calculation. I am thinking I am missing something with classes here (as you eluded to) - but I cannot see how I can get this extra data into the context of the Loaded Event... Would be greatful for further advice!! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly (maybe open a new question with further details if necessary) but if you need data from elsewhere in the dataset (i.e.: not in another item of the dataset) I think the best approach is to access it directly by querying your dataset, rather than trying to extract it from the ListBox items, which is a bit of a "backwards" approach imho.

Comment: Thanks for another response Master_T! Yeah, maybe wasnt too clear but what I was after (have now done) was to pass over the entire datarow for the ListBox Item instead of the single bounded value. I have managed to pass the entire DataRowView in through the bounded DataContext and can now use other values in the dataset row to calculate other rectangles... Im sure that response makes even less sense... but thank you anyway as your initial response got this all pretty much sorted for me! :)